# Disable a device without a confirmation - PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm working on a script that automates the process of disabling multiple Devices in Windows 10. This is my attempt:

```
Get-PnpDevice something | Disable-PnpDevice
```

That code asks the user to enter `y` or `n` to confirm the process of disabling the device.

How to bypass the confirmation prompt to make the script full automatic?

*I always run the script as Administrator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the script uses PowerShell cmdlets, you can specify -**Confirm:$false** to suppress the prompt.

```
Get-PnpDevice something | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
```